# How to change order of taxonomy terms related to specific node field?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, entities

As in question. I have multivalued taxonomy field. Is this possible to control terms weight,  which are belongs to specific node field?

As a term weight, I mean weight inside single node. It's just a field value delta.

Comment: Have you tried re-ordering the terms (changing their weights) in the vocabulary list terms page?

Comment: This will work site wide, but it will not work if you want different orders in different places.

Comment: How exactly are you displaying this field? Because you could just override the node template and do all the custom stuff directly in the template?

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do this. We need to change the taxonomy field widget to autocomplete. Then you can swap the words there, thus changing the delta.